# Taking credit for the public domain work of others

Tags: licensing

I’ve released a piece of code into the public domain (henceforth “PD”), via [The Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/). Recently, I’ve found someone forked that code and made some modifications without any acknowledgment/attribution. That is absolutely fine (it’s to allow that kind of freedom that I’ve released it into the PD in the first place). Fine, that is, until I see that no code was actually changed.

The only changes he did were replacing my name and website for his, and changing the icon.

So what this person did was the equivalent of taking Alice’s Adventures in Wonderland, stripping every reference to Lewis Carroll and replacing them with the equivalent references to himself, changing the cover, and republishing.

No license was attached to it by the person (and the PD one was removed), but this still feels like a dickish thing to do. I’m not exactly bothered by it and am not thinking about pursuing it (it was my decision to put it into the PD, after all) but I’m wondering about not only the ethics but the legality of this. If I understand correctly, PD still does not allow you to take credit for something you haven’t done, and that is still plagiarism. Is that correct, or is it jurisdiction-specific?

Comment: What you're talking about sounds like Moral Rights, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_rights, which goes to the rights authors have to be recognized for their works.

Comment: It could be worse. You evidently created something of value. Imagine being unable to do so; misrepresenting other's work as your own and fearing discovery of your own incompetence.

Comment: This (and the fact that PD doesn't exist in all jurisdictions) is why I personally prefer to use the zlib/png license, which says "The origin of this software must not be misrepresented" and not very much else.

Comment: "No license was attached to it". If the work has no licence attached to it, how did you release it into the public domain? A licence explicitly saying people are free to use it is required, otherwise it's not in the public domain.

Comment: @DavidArno To clarify, I did attach a license to it (a PD one). What I meant is the forker didn’t attach any license to his changes. Edited post with clarification.

Comment: The Unlicense isn't a license in the strictest sense because it doesn't create any obligation for anyone who acquires your software.  Not saying I agree with what was done, but he is within his rights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, PD still does not allow you to take credit for something you haven’t done, and that is still plagiarism. Is that correct, or is it jurisdiction-specific?

I don't believe that to be correct, at least not in the general sense.  Plagiarism can have academic, professional and social implications, but none of those have the force of law unless -- and this is the important part -- doing so infringes on the owner's copyright.

The public domain exists so works can be used by anyone for any purpose once the term of exclusivity (i.e., any copyright or patent) has expired or the author explicitly releases it.  Among those uses is the creation of slightly-derivative versions of public-domain works that don't credit the original author.  It may not be moral or ethical, but according to the U.S. Supreme Court, [it is legal](https://www.oyez.org/cases/2002/02-428).  (Scalia makes some interesting comments in the decision about the implications creating what is essentially a mutant zombie version of copyright law.)  I don't imagine that the courts in any country that's ratified the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) would rule differently.

Preventing that kind of plagiarism is why the plethora of licenses with relatively few restrictions exist and are a better alternative to relinquishing all of your rights by releasing into the public domain.

There are a couple of states (Florida [is one of them](http://law.justia.com/codes/florida/2010/TitleXLVI/chapter877/877_17.html)) that proscribe selling work that the seller knows will be turned in for academic credit.  I don't know how well a law like that would stand up to a legal challenge if the seller has the rights to distribute the work (either through license or because it's in the public domain).

Comment: “Among those uses is the creation slightly-derivative versions of public-domain works that don't credit the original author”. But in this case a derivative work wasn’t made. Only superficial references to it were altered, in a way that conceals the source. The original work wasn’t altered.

Comment: @user137369: A derivative work has to include some or all of the original and some additional element that can be covered by copyright.  There's no qualifier of how much additional material there has to be, so the new icon would count.